# change size of UIImage imageNamed

Tags: ios

I have a retina image that I want to display at 1/2 of the resolution. Is there a command that I can use to display the image at 46px x 40px instead of 91px x 80px?

Code in Xcode:

```
annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"App_Green@2x.png"];
```

Comment: Do you really want to scale 91px to 46px? I'd be tempted to say that making the original 92px is going to give you much nicer results; the sampling is likely to introduce less jarring aliasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"App_Green"];
```

On a retina device, the double-resolution version of the image (i.e. the one with the `@2x` suffix in its name) will be used automatically at the size of the single-resolution image.

Even better, use an asset catalog. Then you don't have to worry about the name of the double-resolution image; just slot it into the catalog.

Comment: ... and if a rumoured triple-resolution or other DPI screen is ever forthcoming you'll just need to update your assets, not your code.